# react-leaflet not working on production build

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

The map is working fine on developing but in production the map disappears

i tried to add

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
    />
```

and this

```
   <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""
    />

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>
```

but they didn't solve the problem

here is the map

```
 <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <MapContainer
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
        center={{ lat: 35.700055681658064, lng: 51.3779310125392 }}
        zoom={13}
        minZoom={5}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
      >
        <TileLayer url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png" />
        <LocationMarker />
        <LocationButton>
          <GpsFixed />
        </LocationButton>
      </MapContainer>
      ,
      <MapSubmitButtonContainer>
        <MapSubmitButton>ثبت</MapSubmitButton>
      </MapSubmitButtonContainer>
      <MapCloseButton>
        <Close />
      </MapCloseButton>
    </div>
```

.................................

Comment: Can you tell us about your build process?  When you examine the elements in devtools, do you see the map elements there (i.e. map container div with children, i.e. panes, overlays, etc).  Is the issue the that the CSS is not included, or is there an issue rendering the components themselves?  We need more info to debug

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i see them, i think the problem was because of using another lealflet url instead of the default one forr the map image,